# Discord.js V12 how to remove mentions from a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot made with `discord.js`, and I want to make a `*say` command.
However, when I write `@everyone`, or role ids (`<@&542542636743557>`), the bot also mentions it.
Is there a way to replace these mentions with `@no` or something?
Here's my code:

```js
if (!args[1]) return msg.channel.send("I can't send an empty message!");
args.shift();
msg.channel.send(args.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Util.cleanContent()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-cleanContent)

```js
const { Util } = require('discord.js')

message.channel.send(Util.cleanContent(message.content, message))
```

```js
message: 'Hello @everyone and @Anunay!'
cleanMessage: 'Hello @everyone and @Anunay!' // looks the same, but doesn't ping
```

[image]